# Isn't there collectstatic equivalent for django collect media command?

Tags: django, deployment

How can I collect media files from different django project applications into one folder to be easier to deploy in production with Nginx/Apache?

Comment: Media files are meant to be uploaded by the user as the site runs, so it doesn't make sense to collect them before deployment.

Comment: please rewrite an answer so that I can pick it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't a `collectstatic` equivalent for media files.

Media files are meant to be uploaded by the user as the site runs, so it doesn't make sense to collect them before deployment.